# I can't assign display:none to a toggle button

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a website which menu is toggleable. but when I am on widescreen the menu is always displayed. I want it to display only when I click the button.

in the html, this is the button:

```
<div class="botonera col-xs-12">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar" id="botonMenu">
       <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
</div>
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#productos"><img class="iconoMenu" src="imagen/iconoMenuProductos.png">Productos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contacto"><img class="iconoMenu" src="imagen/iconoMenuContacto.png">Contacto</a></li>
        <li><a href="#distribuidores"><img class="iconoMenu" src="imagen/iconoMenuDistribuidores.png">Distribuidores</a></li>  
        <li><a href="#cotizacion"><img class="iconoMenu" src="imagen/iconoMenuCotizacion.png">Cotizacion</a></li>                     
        <li><a href="#descargas"><img class="iconoMenu" src="imagen/iconoMenuDemos.png">Descargas</a></li>
        <li><a href="#videos"><img class="iconoMenu" src="imagen/iconoMenuVideos.png">Videos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#nosotros"><img class="iconoMenu" src="imagen/iconoMenuNosotros.png">Nosotros</a></li>
        <li><a href="#faq"><img class="iconoMenu" src="imagen/iconoMenuFaq.png">FAQ</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and this is the css:

```
.navbar-toggle 
{
    display: block !important;
}
.navbar-collapse.collapse 
{
    display: none !important;
}
.navbar-nav>li 
{
    float: none !important;
}
.collapse.in
{
  display:block !important;
}
```

so the problem is i am writing:

```
.navbar-collapse.collapse 
{
   display: none !important;
}
```

but it's not taking it. I am working with bootstrap too. and I think something about it is blocking it. how do I force the menu to be collapsed if it isn't taking the display: none

Comment: Tested in a [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/MDqTyVcV7K), navbar vanishes as expected. So perhaps something is blocking it, but it does not lie in the code you have provided us.

Comment: it is being blocked by a command line in a file named navbar.less:72 but i have no idea how to access it

Comment: Try overriding in-line; or with JavaScript.

Comment: i tried overwriting and it failed... and I don't know how to change it with javascript

Comment: Unless there is a VERY good reason for it, you should remove all of the !important declarations from your css. They make it much more difficult to work with and maintain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. You see, I was writing on my css

```
.navbar-collapse.collapse 
{
    display: none !important;
}
.collapse.in
{
    display:block !important;
}
```

the way I managed to get a grip on those, was just to be more specific. I did that like this:

```
div#navbar.navbar-collapse.collapse 
{
    display: none !important;
}
div#navbar.collapse.in
{
    display:block !important;
}
```

thank you for all your help, I truly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps to achieve what you want:

1. Remove the `collapsed` class from this line: `class="navbar-toggle collapsed"` so it'll look like this: `class="navbar-toggle"`
2. Add this class `navbar-header` to your botonera div like this `class="navbar-header botonera col-xs-12"`
3. Edit your css as follows:

CSS:

```
.navbar-header {
  float: none;
}
.navbar-toggle {
  display: block;
}
.navbar-collapse.collapse {
  display: none!important;
}
.navbar-nav {
  float: none!important;
}
.navbar-nav>li {
  float: none;
}
.navbar-collapse.collapse.in{
  display:block !important;
}
```

Link to jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/8eqdhLwr/1/

Comment: I tried it from scratch with your answer and it still doesn't work... the code in "navbar.less:72" which is this:     display: block!important;  is overwriting everything I do. The thing is I can't get access to it nor overwrite it